# How to apply one model for different categories of interest in python?

Tags: python, pandas, linearmodels

I have a daily sales dataset of 4 items which is sold across 4 different franchises.

I have to build a model to predict the weekly sales of all those 4 items for all the franchises.

I am planning to use one base model for prediction

```
reg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1)
```

My question is how can I code to apply that model across all the 4 products and franchises.

I will appreciate your time and effort to help me. Thank you

My table is like below

```
DepotName    Product    Date        SalesUnits  
    A           A1      2015-01-23  2.0 
    A           A2      2015-01-23  225.0   
    A           A3      2015-01-23  120.0   
    A           A4      2015-01-23  72.0    
    B           A1      2015-01-23  90.0    
    B           A2      2015-01-23  2.0 
    B           A3      2015-01-23  1.0 
    B           A4      2015-01-23  2.0 
    C           A1      2015-01-23  1.0 
    C           A2      2015-01-23  1.0 
    C           A3      2015-01-23  4.0 
    C           A4      2015-01-23  8040.0  
    D           A1      2015-01-23  1590.0  
    D           A2      2015-01-23  1.0     
    D           A3      2015-01-23  1590.0  
    D           A4      2015-01-23  1.0
    A           A1      2015-01-24  2.0 
    A           A2      2015-01-24  225.0   
    A           A3      2015-01-24  120.0   
    A           A4      2015-01-24  72.0    
    B           A1      2015-01-24  90.0    
    B           A2      2015-01-24  2.0 
    B           A3      2015-01-24  1.0 
    B           A4      2015-01-24  2.0 
    C           A1      2015-01-24  1.0 
    C           A2      2015-01-24  1.0 
    C           A3      2015-01-24  4.0 
    C           A4      2015-01-24  8040.0  
    D           A1      2015-01-24  1590.0  
    D           A2      2015-01-24  1.0     
    D           A3      2015-01-24  1590.0  
    D           A4      2015-01-24  1.0
```

Comment: It would help if you tell us how you store the products and franchises.

Comment: Sure , I will update my question in a while

Comment: @PaulaThomas I have updated my question , please check

Comment: I am sorry to be asking another question! Where are you getting linear_model.Ridge from?

Comment: That's okay I got it , 'from sklearn import linear_model'

Comment: I think you probably need to look into pandas' GroupBy and apply methods.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run a `groupby` operation across your indicators:

```
for g in data.groupby(['DepotName', 'Product']):
   # g[0]: TUPLE OF CURRENT GROUP NAMES
   # g[1]: DATAFRAME OF CURRENT GROUP

   predictors = [... list of column names ...]

   reg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1)
   reg.fit(g[1][predictors], g[1]['SalesUnits'])

   y_pred = reg.predict(g[1][predictors])
   # ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait , I really appreciate your help 
However I will try your answer later and update the outcome